# Presonus Firepod sync problem with Mac Yosemite+

Tags: osx, interface

I've got a macbook air that I bought a couple years ago and was very happy with how I could connect my firepod to garage band with no hassle and no configuration.

I bought a brand new macbook pro thinking this would be much more powerful and even better-- but now I can't get the firepod to sync up with the mac. And since I updated the software on my Air, that one won't sync either.

Has anyone got any info on using a firepod with a newer mac? 
Anyone doing this successfully with Yosemite or El Capitan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mavericks is the last version of OS X for firewire audio interface users. I have a [PreSonus - Firepod](https://www.presonus.com/products/FP10) and an [M-Audio firewire 410](https://www.soundonsound.com/sos/mar04/articles/maudio410.htm). neither can be installed on El Capitan. I have rolled back to Mavericks and they work with some problems with S/PDIF.

Companies want you to buy all new equipment every few years, so I am thinking about going back to dedicated recording devices and abandoning computer recording altogether.

I have an old computer - a first generation iMac Intel Core Duo, runs 10.6.8 works with Firewire and Logic 8 and Pro Tools beautifully.

Apple started screwing up after Snow Leopard. Apple has gone downhill since Steve died.

Answer (score 1):

I retired my FirePod for years because Presonus discontinued this product and stopped updating driver to support new versions of OSX.

I gave up when I upgraded OSX to v10.8 Mountain Lion. Presonus states clearly in this page that FirePod/FP10 doesn't support OSX10.8.

http://www.presonus.com/products/FP10/downloads

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the original Firepod (one before FP10) on El capitan. Do not use the Presonus drivers. They are not necessary.   Just plug and play.  Presonus drivers will likely cause a problem.  The hardware however is working fine, with no drop outs or issues.  My computer is a 2008 Mac pro 8 core system. This may be more of a new Mac hardware issue.  I also use successfully the same Firepod with my 2012 Mac mini i7 Quad Core for very stable live performance running Mavericks and Mainstage 2. One thing I always do is use the power switch.  Hot swapping is not recommended on this unit.

Answer (score -1):

Running two firepods daisy chained on Mavericks without any issues.